# Create own Array#map like method

Tags: ruby

I want to create an instance method like `Array#my_map` and that method should behavior of the original `Array#map` method.
I want to same output from new method as below:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.new_map_method do |x|
 x + 1
end # => [2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.new_map_method(&:to_s) # => ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: try using `each` and `push`.

Comment: Ah @sagarpandya82 I want to own method for same output as array map

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? What have you got so far? And by the way, is this homework?

Comment: @Stefan I was using with alias only, so there is requirement for another method

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of creating a method with the same behavior of a different method is a simple [alias](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method):

```
class Array
  alias_method :new_map_method, :map
end
```

If, for whatever strange reason, you don't want to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), you can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) instead:

```
class Array
  def new_map_method
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    inject([]) {|acc, el| acc << yield(el) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe `each_with_object` would be slightly more appropriate.

Comment: Can you explain "return enum_for(__callee__)" here why you took __callee__ what does it mean?

Comment: @uishra: Is there anything unclear about the documentation? What *exactly* is unclear about the documentation?

Comment: I got answer @Stefan
 __callee__ is intended to return the symbol with which the method was actually invoked.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you! i check documentation then understand properly above word

Comment: ...@Stefan's comment ends with ";-)" :-).

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks guys! I also made one solution for my qeestion

```
class Array
 def my_map(&block)
  result = []
  each do |element|
   result << block.call(element)
  end
  result
 end
end
```

> function calling

```
 [1,2,3].my_map(&:to_s)
```

> output => ["1", "2", "3"]

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].my_map do |x|
  x
end
```

> output => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: What about `[1,2,3].my_map`?  See [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for pointing, i am refactoring my code.