# Efficient way to do addition on big array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with +20000 integer elements.

I want to create a new array where each element in the old array is added a modifying number. On a small sample array it would look like this:

```
old_array = [2,5,6,8]
modifying_number = 3
new_array = [5,8,9,11]
```

Is there any more efficient way than doing an iteration like this?

```
class Array
  def addition_by(x)
    collect { |n| n + x }
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems the core `map` wins the day. The question seems now to be now which implementation of Ruby has the fastest `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `N` iterations are the minimal complexity of this algorithm.

You can do it in place by modifying  source array with `collect!`(if you for some reasons not need a source array). Complexity will be the same, additional big object will not created.

Answer (score 3):

20k records is not much to worry about performance.

```
ary = Array.new(20000) { 1 } 
ary.map! { |el| el + 1 }
```

would work totally fine.

I would just suggest to modify the initial array inplace instead of creating a new one (using method with bang), so it will definitely use less resources.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would mean implementing `map` in another way? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39609277/5101493) deals with such a task. I've included benchmarks of the answers by @JörgWMittag and @uishra. Although it has to be said `speed` was not a requirement in the linked question so the answers cannot be criticised in that regard. I've also included @CarySwoveland's answer from this question.

```
require 'fruity'
require 'matrix'

class Array
  #jörg_w_mittag
  def new_map
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    inject([]) {|acc, el| acc << yield(el) }
  end

  #uishra
  def my_map(&block)
    result = []
    each do |element|
     result << block.call(element)
    end
    result
  end

  #cary_swoveland
  def vec_map(k)
    (Vector[*[k]*self.size] + Vector[*self]).to_a
  end

end

arr = (1..30000).to_a
k = 3

10.times do
  compare do
    core_map       { ar = arr.dup; ar.map     { |n| n + k } }
    jörg_w_mittag  { ar = arr.dup; ar.new_map { |n| n + k } }
    uishra         { ar = arr.dup; ar.my_map  { |n| n + k } }
    cary_swoveland { ar = arr.dup; ar.vec_map k }
  end
  puts
end
```

A summary of the results/output:

**Results on five occasions**

```
#Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
#core_map is faster than jörg_w_mittag by 2x ± 1.0
#jörg_w_mittag is similar to uishra
#uishra is similar to cary_swoveland
```

**Results on two occasions**

```
#Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
#core_map is faster than jörg_w_mittag by 2x ± 0.1
#jörg_w_mittag is similar to uishra
#uishra is similar to cary_swoveland
```

**Results on three occasions**

```
#Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
#core_map is faster than uishra by 2x ± 1.0
#uishra is similar to jörg_w_mittag
#jörg_w_mittag is similar to cary_swoveland
```

Comment: sagar, can you add my method to your benchmark? I did so and it tied for last. Incidentally, I ran the benchmark several times. Sometimes uishra was faster than Jörg_W_Mittag, other times not. Wait a minute. Where's Jörg's answer?

Comment: @CarySwoveland he benchmarked answers from the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609277/create-own-arraymap-like-method) :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've updated the benchmarks. My original answer (as does this answer) did include Jörg's answer but I had just changed his method name slightly, but the implementation was the same. If you feel I need to improve my answer let me know. And btw I first discovered `fruity.rb` from one of your previous SO answers so ta for that!

Comment: You need to thank @theTinMan. He's promoted `fruity` in more posts than I can count.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'matrix'

class Array
  def vec_map(k)
    (Vector[*[k]*self.size] + Vector[*self]).to_a
  end
end

[1,2,3].vec_map 4
  #=> [5, 6, 7]
```